# Selecting Python.exe as a interpreter doesnt work?

Tags: python, pycharm

After installing phycharm i get an error message:"Please select a valid Python interpreter".

I went to the python interpreter settings add interpreter system interpreter wrote the path to the python.exe. When I select the Python.exe and click on "Ok" I get an error message:" invalid python interpreter name"python.exe"

I tried reinstalling phycharm and looking for youtube video solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to reinstall python ? And try to use python from cmd to check if your python.exe file does indeed work properly.
Lmk if that doesn't work, but the problem seems kinda weird, dumb question but did you select the python.exe file ? Watch out to not select only the folder.

Comment: when i write "python" in cmd the microsoft store opens up.  i did select the python.exe file. i also tried to reinstall python.

Comment: Did you wrote 'python' while being in the folder where the python executable is found ? Cause else it will always launch microsoft store. If you did that already the problem comes from python itself and not pycharm.

Comment: the folder where the python.exe is sitting was the whole time open while i wrote "python" in cmd but still same result>Microsoft store.

Comment: When i said 'while being' i meant from the cmd use the cd command to access the folder where your .exe is, here's what i meant : open cmd, type 'cd AbsolutePathToYourPyFolder' (for example mine is : cd C:\Users\coren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39) and then type python.

Comment: i fixed it. python path was in the wrong direction.

Comment: Okay nice ty for the update ^^